# Issue on Removing The Margin between li Items

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove all margin between `<li>` list in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/6qjmgtq0/1/) but for what ever reason there is still empty space at the right side of the list

```
ul, li{margin :0px !important; padding :0px !important;}
.list-inline{    margin :0px !important; padding :0px !important;}
.thumbnail{margin :0px !important; padding :0px !important;}
.well {  padding: 0px !important;}
```

I even used the !important to force new rules but even with `*{margin :0px !important; padding :0px !important;}` those space are there! Can you please let me know how to fix this? and remove all free space between `<li>`s

Comment: Here's what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/ud46dLoq/

Comment: Thanks Josh but how did you do that? was it really white space issue?

Comment: Yep. That's all it was. See the linked answer.

Comment: just a quick question?

Comment: Did you use any specific site for HTML beautifying? I mean removing the white space?

Comment: In this case, I did it manually. Normally, I would usually just omit it on the server-side. You could use an HTML minifier, though.